# position absolute with content below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the div class `content` always visible no matter what height of the  div class `banner-text-container` on all screens. `banner-text-container` got dynamic contents inside so its height is not fixed. The requirement is those blue boxes are half on the img-banner-container div and half on the content div. Is there any way to deal with it by `css` or `js`?

```css
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.img-banner-container {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  /*margin-bottom: 200px;*/
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("http://www.lanlinglaurel.com/data/out/162/5403600-wallpaper-hd.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /*height: auto;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.banner-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.banner-text-content {
  padding: 0 20%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/*.content-with-nav-boxes {*/


/*background-color: white;*/


/*position: relative;*/


/*padding: 0 10%;*/


/*margin-bottom: 50px;*/


/*height: 500px;*/


/*width: 100%;*/


/*overflow-x: hidden;*/


/*}*/

.small-nav-boxes {
  /*padding: 0 10%;*/
  /*clear: both;*/
  width: 100%;
}

.small-nav-boxes .single-nav-box {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 33.33%!important;
  float: left!important;
}

.single-nav-box {
  padding: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0091CF;
}

.content {
  background-color: #4C4145;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .small-nav-boxes .single-nav-box {
    width: 100%!important;
    float: none!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-banner-container">
  <div class="banner-text-container">
    <h1 class="banner-text-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <div class="banner-text-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In purus leo, blandit sit amet hendrerit non, lobortis id arcu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam tempor eu urna vitae aliquam. Donec convallis
      ullamcorper massa. Nam interdum pulvinar libero, a lobortis nunc congue eu. Vestibulum vel elit et metus feugiat faucibus. Ut aliquet dui leo, quis imperdiet quam tincidunt sit amet. Etiam sed nibh efficitur, tincidunt justo a, dapibus dui. In quam
      ipsum, dapibus id convallis vulputate, porttitor et erat. Vivamus eget tellus sit amet nulla aliquet pharetra. Cras sed lorem euismod, maximus urna non, condimentum lacus. Nullam eleifend nunc eget magna ultrices eleifend.
      <br/> Aliquam vel porta quam. Sed a blandit purus. Proin non magna in enim aliquam mollis. Quisque lacus ex, ultrices id nulla scelerisque, suscipit congue risus. Mauris tincidunt gravida semper. Fusce a consectetur lorem. Praesent molestie consequat
      leo, vel egestas mi mollis eu. Quisque non pharetra orci, vitae dapibus sem. Sed pharetra facilisis interdum. Aenean a posuere lorem, et bibendum augue. Vestibulum quis auctor tortor. Suspendisse porta facilisis erat et dignissim. Nulla commodo
      enim tellus, eget vestibulum felis bibendum vel. In semper erat id lacus venenatis tincidunt. Sed a nulla quis leo porttitor porta.
      <br/> Proin erat ipsum, vestibulum ac lacus a, luctus gravida arcu. Curabitur tincidunt varius finibus. Suspendisse at nibh erat. Sed in lobortis mi, in lobortis felis. Phasellus tincidunt tincidunt porta. Nulla non ipsum ullamcorper, egestas dui
      in, rhoncus orci. Nulla malesuada mauris nec nibh porta facilisis. Etiam finibus purus non ex accumsan, accumsan lacinia lectus rutrum. Etiam molestie neque id lectus condimentum ullamcorper. Quisque nunc nisl, venenatis vel diam vitae, facilisis
      pharetra massa. Curabitur fringilla mollis vulputate. Donec fermentum lorem felis.
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="small-nav-boxes">
      <div class="single-nav-box">
        <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
      <div class="single-nav-box">
        <p>Why do we use it?</p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
      <div class="single-nav-box">
        <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
        content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
        versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but I understood more from looking at your code directly.

It seems to me that you're using absolute positioning where is not needed, and also using way too many !important declarations when you should almost-never use them.

I modified your code to keep the "content" block present at all times. If the content above it will change its size due to dynamically generated content, then it should grow naturally and follow the flow of the page. No need to set heights or use absolute positioning.

Here is your CSS, modified: https://jsfiddle.net/ronaldpoi/e434hy5w/

**EDIT:** With more information about the desired outcome, I updated the code. In this scenario you do have to use absolute positioning to control the elements. You'll also need to add html markup to make it possible. I updated my code in the Jsfiddle.

Here is the second modification: https://jsfiddle.net/ronaldpoi/e434hy5w/1/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.img-banner-container {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("http://www.lanlinglaurel.com/data/out/162/5403600-wallpaper-hd.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-bottom: 180px;
}

.banner-text-container {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.small-nav-boxes-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.small-nav-boxes {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.single-nav-box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #0091CF;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #4C4145;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 180px;
}
```

Comment: the requirement is that those blue boxes are half on the img-banner-container div and half on the content div

Comment: It does not work on 1024px screen and below. Please check

Comment: I'll leave the responsive settings to you. Basically, you'd only need to remove the absolute positionings, the height in the new container for the panels and the padding in the adjacent panels.